# How does control flow after socket close?

Tags: c++, sockets, event-handling, network-programming

```
//pseudo code - actual code in c++
Process P1 code:
func handle_close() {
   print "close";
}

func sayhello() {
    print "hello";
}

func writeonsocketforP2() {
   write(fd, somedata, somedata_sz);
}

func WriteToP2() {
    count = 0;
    while (count++ != 1000000) writeonsocketforP2();
    sayhello();
}
```

Consider the scenario:

1. Socket connection established between process P1(single threaded) and P2
2. P1 in a loop writing a huge amount of data to socket for P2 from WriteToP2 function
3. P2 goes down while P1 is still writing and P1 got socket close event and close event handler handle_close invoked..lets say this happened when count was 1000
4. After that handle_close is invoked will control go back to while loop and continue the while loop from count 1001?
5. Will sayhello() invoked after the socket close in the middle of while loop  in WriteToP2

Comment: @Scheff'sCat yes..pseudo code...actual code of app in c++..edited to put comment

Answer (score 1):

That's why you need to check if `write()` returns error code for writing on socket(assuming connection-oriented socket like `TCP`). `write()` return `-1` if an error while writing on socket happens which includes a closed socket.

In addition, in your code `sayhello()` will not be called till loop finishes. Normally `WriteToP2()` needs another thread, unless you can write non-blocking code.

Comment: Side note: If P2 goes down without handshaking, it may take a while to realize it even with proper error checking. `write` calls won't start failing until the send window fills up.

Comment: @user4581301 you mean before connection handshake?yea, but in that case `connect` returns error (after a long time) and we should not `write` at all.

Comment: No, I mean after connection. Successful connection, start sending data, other side vanishes without closing connection. TCP will keep trying to send whatever's been written to the stack for a very long time and will allow `write` to keep adding until the window is full. Part of TCP's survival mechanisms.

Comment: @user4581301 yea, it is true. But cannot do much about it.